# How to organize celery task in simple python flask app?

Tags: python, flask, celery

I have a simple flask application using Celery. Right now the code looks like this.

Here's my server.py which is at the root directory

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import os
import json
import logging
import requests
import sys

app = Flask(__name__)

# app.debug = True
app.config.update(
    CELERY_BROKER_URL=config.get('REDISTOGO_URL'),
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=config.get('REDISTOGO_URL'),
)
celery = make_celery(app)

@celery.task(bind=False, default_retry_delay=30)
def convert(gif_url, webhook):
    // Do some heavy lifting task

@app.route("/convert", methods=["POST"])
def convert():
    // Call the task
```

And this is my `make_celery(app)`

```
from celery import Celery


def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task

    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

The reason that I'm confused is because it looks like if I extract the task to another file called `convert_task.py` then that file has to import `app` and `make_celery` and in the app has to import `convert_task.py`

which I tried and I get

> cannot import name 'app'

What's the pythonic way to organize this. The reason behind this we will add more task to `server.py` which I don't want that to become a god file.

Answer (score 0):

I have been developing a flask app that uses Celery, so here is what I have done that works for me:

- `make_celery` is defined in the same file where the app instance is created (looks like `server.py` in your case)
- My tasks are defined in a separate `tasks.py` which lives in the same directory as `server.py`. This is also where i instantiate my celery object (from `make_celery`)
- When spinning up a celery worker, use the -A switch and then give it the path to tasks.py

I hope this helps some, let me know if you have any other questions as to how I've organized my app.

Comment: Do you have any repo on github.com i can take a look? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately the project is in an internal git repo that's only accessible from my company's network, but if you have any specific questions I would be happy to give you more details.

Comment: This [blog post](https://medium.com/@rahulrrixe/hacking-celery-task-14c9867f0711) was very helpful for me when I was starting out with celery tasks.

Answer (score -1):

You're probably getting a [circular import](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm#circular-imports).

You can fix it by doing one of these:

1. Moving the import that is failing to the bottom of the file.
2. Moving the import into the function that is using the import (not at the top level of the module).
3. Reorganizing your modules so that both `convert_task` and `server` are importing from a third module which does not import from either of those files.

If you are still having trouble please post the exact layout of the files and what is importing what. It should be easy to reproduce the issue with a few lines of code (excluding the flask / celery specific stuff).